# Cannot read property 'length' of null on matching current window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I am trying to match a URL, and dependent on if an ID is present in the URL I will add a class which will trigger an overlay.

If I navigate to the url with the following added at the end: `?active-overlay=jj-instagram-feed-widget-2`, I get the overlay triggered, and everything is working.

However if I navigate directly to the page without the `active-overlay` URL parameter, I get the following console error:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of null.
```

Im guessing the error is fired because that it cannot find `active-overlay` in the URL.

How can I get around this?

Here is my code:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.match("active-overlay").length > 0) {
    var activeOverlayID = url.match(/=(.+)/)[1];
    $('#' + activeOverlayID + '').find('.instagram-feed__image').siblings().addClass('popup');
}
```

Comment: means there is no match, simple debugging would have shown you that. `console.log("match: ", url.match("active-overlay"))`

Comment: Mikkel check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check for `null` before that condition check

```
 url.match("active-overlay") !== null
```

So your code will be,

```
var url = window.location.href;
var matchUrl = url.match("active-overlay");
if (matchUrl !== null && matchUrl.length > 0) {
    var activeOverlayID = url.match(/=(.+)/)[1];
    $('#' + activeOverlayID + '').find('.instagram-feed__image').siblings().addClass('popup');
}
```

So if the `matchUrl` is `null` the statement becomes `false` and will not move on to the next condition of `&&`. As '&&' results to false if any of the preceding condition is `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your help AKA, this solve the issues. I will approve your answer as the solution, as soon as the time-limit has passed :)

Comment: Thanks @MikkelFennefoss . Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
if (url.match("active-overlay")!=null && url.match("active-overlay").length > 0) {
    var activeOverlayID = url.match(/=(.+)/)[1];
    $('#' + activeOverlayID + '').find('.instagram-feed__image').siblings().addClass('popup');
}
```